# JWT and Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, jjwt

I've built a REST Service using Spring Boot and Spring Security for authentication. I'm pretty new to both Spring Boot and Spring Security. I've made one authentication module in one JAR file. The front end client sends a request with username and password to the authentication module. The authentication module then authenticates the user's details against a DB. A JWT is created and then sent back to the client if the authentication is successful. The username and role is coded into the JWT. The JWT is then used to verify the user when resources are requested from the other REST Service endpoints that are built in separate JAR files. There are a few things I'm not sure about.

In Spring Security is there one authentication object created for each user so that several users can be authenticated at the same time or is one authentication done each time and only one user can be logged in?

How long is the authentication object in valid? Should I "logout"/remove the authentication successful when the JWT has been created in the authentication module or will it take care of it itself when the request is done? For the resource endpoints (not the authentication endpoint) is there a way to set authentication successful in the authentication object once I've verified the JWT? Similarly can I set the role in the authentication object once the JWT has been verified?

I've based my code on this example https://auth0.com/blog/securing-spring-boot-with-jwts/. I've split it into different JARs for authentication and verification of the JWT (I'm doing verification in resource endpoint). I've also added JDBC authentication instead of in memory authentication.

Comment: Token expiry, session expiration, revoking tokens...You might find it easier just to use traditional cookies as advocated in this Spring blog. https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii#help-how-is-my-application-going-to-scale. Also http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/

Answer (score 1):

> In Spring Security is there one authentication object created for each
>   user so that several users can be authenticated at the same time or is
>   one authentication done each time and only one user can be logged in?

Of course multiple users can be authenticated at the same time!

> How long is the authentication object in valid? Should I
>   "logout"/remove the authentication successful when the JWT has been
>   created in the authentication module or will it take care of it itself
>   when the request is done?

You write your service is REST, and if you want to stay "puritan" REST you should configure the authentication to be **stateless**, which means that the `Authentication` object is removed when the request has been processed. This does not affect the validity of the JWT token, you can set an expiry of JWT token if you want.

How to make REST stateless with "Java config":

```java
@Configuration
public static class RestHttpConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        // and the rest of security config after this
```

> For the resource endpoints (not the authentication endpoint) is there
>   a way to set authentication successful in the authentication object
>   once I've verified the JWT? Similarly can I set the role in the
>   authentication object once the JWT has been verified?

I use code similar to below *after* verification of the token:

```java
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_JWT"));
Authentication authentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(subject, token, authorities);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

By constructing the authentication object with at least one role (authority), it is marked as "successful" (authenticated).

Comment: Thanks for the input.Is there one Authentication Manager created for each user or is there one Authentication Manager where each user is separated by username `auth.getUsername()`? To make the authentication stateless should I run something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/33032486/2420986 after the request has been processed?

Comment: @g3blv There is usually only one `AuthenticationManager` per system, which has the overall responsibility to _authenticate_ users, it does not store the users. Regarding stateless, se update (edit).